# Swift Package Manager - Exclude dependency

Tags: ios, swift, dependencies, swift-package-manager

I'm having a second thought using multiple products inside SPM. Here is the thing.

I’ll provide two products in the package. One is “Tool” and the other one is “ToolNetworking”.
The first one has some swift classes, nothing special, no dependencies at all.
The second one also has some swift logic, but a dependency on Alamofire lib.

Here is the config:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "Tool",
  platforms: [.iOS(.v11)],
  products: [
    .library(name: “Tool", targets: [“Tool"]),
    .library(name: “ToolNetworking", targets: [“ToolNetworking"])
  ],
  dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", .exact("5.1.0"))
  ],
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "Tool",
      path: "Sources",
      exclude: ["Networking"]
    ),
    .target(
      name: "ToolNetworking",
      dependencies: ["Tool", "Alamofire"],
      path: "Sources",
      sources: ["Networking"]
    )
  ],
  swiftLanguageVersions: [.v5]
)
```

When I want to install the package, I can choose between the two. If I select `ToolNetworking`, it will also install `Alamofire` dependency.

For `Tool` product I only want SPM to install my code, no dependencies. Here is my question. How can I exclude `Alamofire` when I install only `Tool` product since I didn't define a `dependencies` field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first step would be to upgrade to Swift 5.2. The Swift Package Manager shipped with Swift 5.2 starts to implement exactly this behaviour (as described in [SE-0226](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0226-package-manager-target-based-dep-resolution.md)).

However, since it's not fully implemented yet, it could be that Xcode will still check out Alamofire. It should not link it in the end, though. So if you only use the `Tool` product, the resulting binary will not have any traces of Alamofire inside it :-)

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't notice this is already in progress. I've checked and I'm already using Swift version 5.2.2. But the dependency is still there for `Tool` product.

Comment: In your code above you're using `// swift-tools-version:5.1`. You'd have to use `// swift-tools-version:5.2` for the new feature to be used.

Comment: I've just tried this. Xcode *will* check out the dependencies used by other products, but it will *not* link them (as described). The part where those dependencies will not even be cloned is still in progress. But this should be something that will be added in a future swift version and thus you should get "automatically" at some point... :)

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate it  I hope it will get in with the next iteration.